# Is this a good way to check for loss of data on cast operation in C?

Tags: c, casting, range

I am "downcasting" (not in the OOP sense, but casting from a bigger datatype to a smaller datatype) like so:

```
uint_16 big = 99;
uint_8 small = 0;
// ... do stuff


if( (uint_16)((uint_8)big) == big) { // or if(big&0x00FF == big)
    small = (uint_8)big;
    // no problem
} else {
    // problem
}
```

of course, I already know all my ranges since the datatypes are fixed length, but I feel like comparing to 0x00FF directly would cause more complicated logic in the long run as I develop  the program further. Is that really even better performance-wise or in any other way? (cast vs. comparison operation).

Basically, the main thing I am asking is if there are any "gotchas" that I am overlooking here. The above seems like a good way of doing it to me.

EDIT: uint_8 and uint_16 are examples, but I also would like this to work with signed to unsigned conversions for example from int16 to uint8 or uint16 to int16.

Comment: This should work.  But you could just use `if (big <= UINT8_MAX)`.

Comment: Or you could use `if (big >> 8 == 0)` or `if (big & 0xFF00 == 0)`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - That's not a comment, that's the answer (although the edit asks for elaboration to other types). Would you like to post it as the answer, or shall I?  :)

Comment: does seem cleaner now that I look at it. I added a signedness-conversion requirement, but even then it's not bad with an OR statement. Let's wait and see if anybody comes up with some cool and creative way of accomplishing this rather mundane task.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth. Yes, if this really does turn out to be a trivial yes/no question, someone should still get the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest expression of what you want is this:

```
if (big <= UINT8_MAX)
```

You can extend this to signed types:

```
if (big <= INT8_MAX && big >= INT8_MIN)
```

This requires two comparisons; I imagine there may be some fancy bit-twiddling ways to avoid that, but it certainly wouldn't be as clear (and probably wouldn't be any faster, in practice).

Comment: The fancy bit-twiddling solutions are more likely to have portability issues, especially on machines that don't use two's complement arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

OP's approach of casting to the destination type and then back again to the original type vs. this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797926/2410359) which tests against `_MIN` & `_MAX` could well generate the same code and clarity of coding should direct the choice.

But if the types were floating point like going from `double` to `float`, these approaches are  very different operations.  FP types have a range and precision to consider.  Typically only range is the issue.  If so, use 2 compares against `-FLT_MAX` and `+FLT_MAX`.

If FP range *and* precision "loss of data" are of concern, round tripping via the OP's 2 casts would work.  Some special coding may be needed as C allows FP intermediate results to occur at a higher precision.

```
double source;
// `source` set somehow in code
volatile float dest = (float) source;
volatile double test = (double) dest;
if (test != source) Oops();
```

Note: With floating point, Infinity and Not-a-number complicate this check.

Comment: I don't think the question makes much sense if applied to floating point types.  You will always loose information when casting a `double` to a `float`.  “All remaining bits zero” is information, too.

Comment: "always loose information when casting a `double` to a `float`" is not so in simple processors that use the same FP for both.  I would suggest "All remaining bits" in _any fixed_ pattern is not information.

Comment: That are some nice points to consider.  However, I don't understand your code sample.  What is `test`?

Comment: @5gon12eder `test` _was_ a coding error.  Now corrected.   By using `volatile`, the value saved should be of that type and prevents the compiler from using a larger type.

Comment: +1 for the updated answer.  Suggesting you make the cast in line 2 explicit and add a comment to `source` to make clear you are not using an uninitialized value.